# setup apache and mod_fastcgi to work with php-fpm not working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, php-fpm, fastcgi

I try to setup php-fpm with apache

I am still missing a piece of the puzzle, because the page returns a 404

```
The requested URL /php-fpm/index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 Server at test.dev Port 80
```

From what I understand sofar is that the path mentioned in the alias does not have to exist, but it should match with the following ExternalServer directive. The socket path is exactly the same as has been set in the php-fpm config. I chmodded -R 777 the var and the tmp directory and the site directory. I saw that the socket and the fastcgi have the same owners "_www", those are the default settings and saw no need to change them.

php54 --with-php-fpm, mod_fastcgi are installed with Homebrew, but [this guide](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/blob/master/Contributions/Using%20FPM.md) did not help me either

What else can I do? Any suggestions very much appreciated.

this is what is in my httpd

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
 #   <FilesMatch \.php$>
   #     SetHandler php-script
 #   </FilesMatch>
 #   Action php-script /php.external
#    Alias   /php.external   /var/run/mod_fastcgi/php.fpm
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
Action php-fastcgi /php-fpm
 Alias   /php-fpm   /var/run/mod_fastcgi/php.fpm

    FastCGIExternalServer /var/run/mod_fastcgi/php.fpm -socket /tmp/php-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization
    AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.cgi index.html index.htm
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes +MultiViews
    <Directory "/var/run/mod_fastcgi/">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        <Files "php.fpm">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>


<VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/testsite/public"  
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias www.test.dev
  <Location /php-fpm>
              Order Deny,Allow
              Deny from all
              Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
          </Location>
```

Comment: what is the exact benefit please to use mod_fastcgi instead of proxying all request with mod_proxy_fcgi to fpm? It sounds to me as another layer which is not necessary because FPM itself is FastCGI implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with Apache 2.2 and PHP-FPM for days, until I realized that it didn't work unless `FastCgiWrapper` was set to `Off`. Not sure if this makes any difference for you, but it fixed my problems. Be aware that *any* FastCgi scripts executed by Apache will *not* run through suexec after this. PHP-FPM does not need this, but you may have other FastCgi instances running.

Comment: It might be usefull if I could find the directive?